# How to delete and/or merge dev/sda5 logical filesystem?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto my primary computer, replacing Ubuntu 11.10. I used the fresh install method, wiping all data off of the HDD and starting from scratch using a flash drive for the 12.04 installation.

Upon first boot at the Ubuntu loading screen, a message appears indicating Ubuntu is mounting a separate partition. It gives me the option to wait, or cancel and mount manually later.

I have never made a separate partition, but for some reason I had a 1 GB sized partition laying around on my system after installation.

I don't know why or how it is there, because like I said I JUST installed 12.04. The partition is a logical, 1012 MB sized unknown file system.

[image: Here is the useless partition]

[image: Here is the partitions information]

So, my question is, I would like to know if I can merge it back into my primary partition. Because the partition slows boot up time, and is pretty useless to me. I would also like to know what exactly happened, and how I can prevent it in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deleting that 1GB partiton and then extending dev/sda1.
I'm guessing, but could it be that you used the 'Try Ubuntu' option before installing it to hard disc permanently??

For Ubuntu you need to have a 'Swap' partition, and my guess is that this what the !GB was intended for at installation. rather than deleting it I'd suggest you format it as a 'Swap' partition.

To format the 1GB partition, place your mouse pointer over the respective line in the Gparted window and click your RH mouse button. Up will pop a menu offering 'Format'. Click the LH button on the word 'Format'. You will then see a small pop-up window offering a seletcion of different formats, choose 'Swap', then OK out of it all.

But if you really do want to delete it then::-MOST IMPORTANT>>>>>> BE VERY CAREFUL THAT YOU DO NOT DELETE THE MAIN PARTITION BY ACCIDENT.

To delete the 1GB partition, place your mouse pointer over the respective line in the Gparted window and click your RH mouse button. Up will pop a menu offering 'delete'. Click the LH button on the word 'delete'.

Following that you can repeat the operation to delete the 1GB extended partition. You'll then have some unallocated space which can be used to extend you main partition.

To extend your main partition you place your mouse pointer over the respective line in the Gparted window and click your RH mouse button. Up will pop a menu offering 'move/resize'. Click the LH button on the word 'move/resize'.

I think you'll be able to work out what to do there.

AT ALL TIMES DOUBLE CHECK WHAT YOU ARE ABOUT TO DO. Good luck.

Comment: Its cool. The try Ubuntu can be done again and gparted can do its operations on the partitions. It need not be before installation onto hard disk.

Comment: How would I do this?